Cannot login to backend after upgrade to Magento 2.4.7-p1
After upgrading to Magento 2.4.7-p1 I am seeing the following error when trying to login into the backend:
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Error in merged XML after reading /var/www/dev/magento2/vendor/magento/module-config/etc/acl.xml
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 19
The xml was: 
14:                            <!--
15:                            @deprecated Magento_Config::advanced section ('Advanced Section') is disabled and is not displayed in the admin panel
16:                            -->
17:                            <resource id="Magento_Config::advanced" title="Advanced Section" translate="title" sortOrder="90" disabled="true"/>
18:                            <resource id="Magento_Config::config_admin" title="Advanced Admin Section" translate="title" sortOrder="100"/>
19:                            <resource id="Magento_Config::config_design" title="Design Section" translate="title" sortOrder="40"/>
20:                            <resource id="Magento_Config::config_general" title="General Section" translate="title" sortOrder="20"/>
21:                            <resource id="Magento_Config::config_system" title="System Section" translate="title" sortOrder="80"/>
22:                            <resource id="Magento_Config::currency" title="Currency Setup Section" translate="title" sortOrder="120"/>
23:                            <resource id="Magento_Config::dev" title="Developer Section" translate="title" sortOrder="110"/>


A workaround for this problem after upgrading to Magento 2.4.7 is to edit the following file:
/vendor/magento/framework/Acl/etc/acl_merged.xsd

Modify
<xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="required" />

Change to
<xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="optional" />

See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38839 for more info.

Check you ACL's of all modules. As error says title is required. But it throws error which shows core code. I suspect there is a module that has invalid acl.
To find it easily I would go to the \Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder::getAcl
Add a temporary logger (remove it afterwards)
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info();

And Try to log whatever is happening there. Maybe try to get info from $this->_acl object.
This is usually how I find invalid xmls after Magento updates.
Or another way - disable custom modules one by one (or do binary search by disabling half of the custom modules and checking results, if issue persists - disable half of what is left and continue until you find it).
